# How do I split a string with two different delimiters in Ruby and convert it to two arrays?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, split

I have a string

```
"Param 1: 1, Some text: 2, Example3: 3, Example4: 4"
```

and I'd like to convert it into an arrays:

```
["Param 1","Some text","Example3","Example4"]
[1,2,3,4]
```

How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *plenty* of ways to do it in Ruby.

You can first split by pairs' delimiter (comma) and then use map to split further by key/pair delimiter (colon):

```
pairs = s.split(/,\s*/).map { |s| s.split(/:\s*/) }
keys = pairs.map(&:first)
values = pairs.map(&:last)
```

(here and below `s` is your original string)

You can use `scan` to match keys/values in a single call (disclaimer: it does NOT mean this is more efficient - regexps aren't magic)

```
pairs = s.scan(/(?<key>[^:]+):\s*(?<value>[^,]+)[,\s]*/)
keys = pairs.map(&:first)
values = pairs.map(&:last)
```

(named captures aren't necessary here - with `scan` they don't give any benefits - but I put them to make regexp arguably a bit more readable)

You can split by all delimiters and then use `Enumerable#partition` to separate keys from values, smth. like:

```
keys, values = s.split(/:\s*|,\s*/).partition.with_index { |_, i| i.even? }
```

etc...

Comment: I like the last one!

Comment: Alternatively `keys, values = pairs.transpose`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a one liner that uses [Multiple Assignment](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Multiple+Assignment) to create 2 new named arrays:

```
a1, a2 = str.split(", ").map{|x| x.split(": ")}.transpose

a1 #=>  ["Param 1", "Some text", "Example3", "Example4"]
a2 #=>  ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

Although most of this solution has already been mentioned in one form or another in previous suggestions, I prefer this combined approach over others mentioned for a few reasons:

1. It doesn't utilize regex which makes it execute quicker than some of the other suggestions.  Actually, after running a few quick benchmarks, it looks like it actually executes faster than the other non-regex solution listed so far as well.
2. It simultaneously creates 2 unique and individually named arrays to work with (as opposed to just creating an array with 2 sub arrays).
3. It carries out the whole operation with one line.

Comment: `a1, a2 = (n = str.split(", ").map{|x| x.split(": ")}.transpose)[0],  n[1]` is too noisy and can be simplified to `a1, a2 = str.split(", ").map{|x| x.split(": ")}.transpose`

Comment: @engineersmnky, Good one!  I didn't realize we could do that.  I'll edit my post.

Comment: NOTE:  I don’t see it covered in the Multiple Assigment documentation I linked in my answer above and strangely, not all documentation seems to agree on this subject, but as shown in my edited example above, Multiple Assignment CAN be used for Array Decomposition WITHOUT parentheses. Here’s another source where this is pointed out.  https://riptutorial.com/ruby/example/8798/decomposition

Comment: while you are correct that it is not explicitly stated in the documentation, using an explicit Array literal e.g `a,b =[1,2]` every example of multiple assignment uses implicit Array syntax e.g. `a,b = 1,2` in this case `1,2` is an implicit Array per the documentation meaning it is interpreted in the exact same way as an explicit Array.

Answer (score 1):

Input

```
a = "Param 1: 1, Some text: 2, Example3: 3, Example4: 4"
```

Code

```
obj= a.split(',').map { |x| x.split(':') }    
p obj.map(&:first).map(&:strip)    
p obj.map(&:last)
```

Result

```
["Param 1", "Some text", "Example3", "Example4"]
[" 1", " 2", " 3", " 4"]
```

Comment: You can split on `', '` and `': '` (both with a space) to avoid the `strip`.

Comment: Yes sure thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-split) with a regular expression, then pair the returned values and transpose:

```
str = "Param 1: 1, Some text: 2, Example3: 3, Example4: 4"
```

```
str.split(/[:,] +/).each_slice(2).to_a.transpose
  #=> [["Param 1", "Some text", "Example3", "Example4"],
  #    ["1", "2", "3", "4"]]
```

The steps are as follows.

```
a = str.split(/[:,] +/)
  #=> ["Param 1", "1", "Some text", "2", "Example3", "3", "Example4", "4"]
```

The regular expression reads, "match a colon or comma followed by one or more spaces".

```
enum = a.each_slice(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["Param 1", "1", "Some text", "2", "Example3",
  #                  "3", "Example4", "4"]:each_slice(2)>
b = enum.to_a
  #=> [["Param 1", "1"], ["Some text", "2"], ["Example3", "3"],
  #    ["Example4", "4"]]
b.transpose
  #=> [["Param 1", "Some text", "Example3", "Example4"],
  #    ["1", "2", "3", "4"]]
```

---

Here is a second way to perform the calculation that I present without explanation, except to say that it uses the form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that takes one argument and no block, returning an enumerator that can be chained to [Enumerator#with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object). This form of `gsub`, unlike the others, does not perform character substitutions (and therefore may be considered misnamed). Rather, the enumerator generates and returns matches of its argument, here a regular expression.

```
str.gsub(/[a-z][a-z ]+\d*(?=:)|\d+(?![^,])/i).with_object([[],[]]) do |s,(a,b)|
 (s[0].match?(/\d/) ? b : a) << s
end
  #=> [["Param 1", "Some text", "Example3", "Example4"],
  #    ["1", "2", "3", "4"]]
```